# How do I access crash dumps from Agentless Exception Monitoring?

Tags: crash-dumps, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-error-reporting

I've just set up a test of Corporate Error Reporting (CER) using Agentless Exception Monitoring (AEM) running as part of System Center Operations Manager 2012 R2 (SCOM) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials with Update.

In any case, I *do* have everything set up. I have two virtual machines (one the server / one a test client to crash a program on). I can go ahead and crash a program on the client and sure enough, a dump is taken and the error shows up in SCOM's AEM page. Great. I can manually browse deep in my configured `ErrorData` folder and I do eventually find a `.cab` file that has the dump I'm interested in. There must be a better way to get the dump file.

Here's my question: **How do I access the dump for a specific error from within SCOM (on the server or the web interface)?**

I'm trying to figure out the developer workflow -- and as a developer myself, I want the crash dump. Again, I am able to manually browse through a long path (several folders deep with non-intuitive names -- a red flag for me that I shouldn't be browsing this way).

The long path (note that `CERTESTSRV` and `CERTESTINT` are the server/domain names -- probably not needed for this problems sake):
`\\CERTESTSRV.CERTESTINT.local\ErrorData\PersistedCabs\Generic\APPCRASH\CrashProject.exe\0.0.0.0\56a01172\MSVCR120.dll\12.0.21005.1\524f7ce6\40000015\000a7676\b22863e6-3b7f-4447-93c6-ae80c30384e6.cab`

I set up the server based on: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh457006.aspx

Note: I'm unsure if this question is better suited here or on SuperUser. I decided to put it here as it's somewhat development related.

Comment: The path is just non-intuitive as long as you don't know what all those numbers mean. It may be very helpful if you're looking for something particular. A guess: exe name + exe version + exe hash + crash causing DLL + DLL version + hash + exception code + a unique name in case the same crash happens again on a different machine or for a different user. To me, this feature looks like Windows Error Reporting of Microsoft. Ain't there a website where things are presented nicely?

Comment: This is Windows Error Reporting =). I can see most things rather nicely in OpsMgr (System Center Operations Manager 2012 R2) -- and it does provide that path for me based on the error I have selected. That path ends with a cab file -- and what I'm really wondering is if there is an easier way for a developer to get a mini-dump associated with a crash *other than* manually navigating to that path and extracting the dump. Maybe a way from within OpsMgr.

Comment: And there's no http://CERTESTSRV.CERTESTINT.local website similar to MS http://sysdev.microsoft.com (formerly http://winqual.microsoft.com/)?

Comment: I've never used the public winqual or sysdev, but there is a web interface for OpsMgr that I set up -- and it does have error views. It's not a huge issue either way. I'm new to full on Corporate Error Reporting with OpsMgr and Agentless Exception Monitoring and thought there would be an easier way to get at the minidumps than manually browsing/extracting. I'll have to look into how winqual works and see if I can draw parallels to OpsMgr. Both of these things are ultimately using Windows Error Reporting -- so I imagine they're similar.